# HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request, code = 303003, detail = Could not generate access token for oauth configured http endpoint null

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

We are passing the token URL, clientID and client Secret, even in logs we are able to see still we are getting "**HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request, code = 303003, detail = Could not generate access token for oauth configured http endpoint null org.apache.synapse.endpoints.auth.AuthException: Error while accessing the Token URL.**"

Could you please help me to understand this log why we are getting endpoint as null even after passing the values properly.

please find the log below.

[2023-11-29 14:17:23,504]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - sourceEndpointURL = https://www.123enterpriseb2b.com/u/box/1.0/post, sourceTokenURL = https://logmein.microsoftonlineto.com/161/oauth2/1.0/token, SClient_ID = cccc9be-b9e6-6d8dd14a7f0d, SClient_Secret = xxxxC2uWceRlIrVrU2IYQdw7EaYO, SScope = default
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,505]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - destEPSecScheme = OAUTH2
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,507]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - oAuth2 * isDestinationEPAvailable = 1
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,508]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - oAuth2 * destEndpointURL = https://www.test2.co.in/1.0/switch, destConnectionTimedOut = 5, destTokenURL = https://www.test2.co.in/oauth/accesstoken, DClient_ID = xx4vvvIoxxxxxxxxxxx, DClient_Secret = mkmkkkgLVnBcmmm, DScope = default
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,508]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - I am = StateTransitionSequence
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,509]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - I am = messageInstancesSequence
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,509]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - I am = Get currentRetry
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,517]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - MI.ID = 405729
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,518]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - currentRetryNumber + 1 = 1
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,530]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - Info2 = *****currentRetry updated******
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,539]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - Info1 = *****MessageStateTransitions Entry added******
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,539]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - I am = messageInstancesSequence
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,540]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - I am = Update cusrrentState into MessageInstances, currentState = Dispatched, routingID = residentialSwitchMatchRequest, s_identity = RRRR
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,541]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - isRetry = 1
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,541]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:746961cf-b9c0-4ce8-942b-f0af1954d32d, correlation_id: 61a83143-685b-47b1-a7e6-1e3cb1864167_e13f2391-71cd-464b-bbe5-1e0ff7e78522, Direction: request, Payload: {"xxxxxxxxxxxx": "xxxx"}
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,548]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - UpdateMessageInstance MI.ID = 405729
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,558]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - Info2 = *****Message Entry updated******
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,619]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - StatusCode from Endpoint = 400

[2023-11-29 14:17:23,619]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - Message = 40X Exception from Destination!!!, statusCode = 400
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,619]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - Info = I am 400 so 9006 Unable to deliver the message to the destination, rejected, invalid message format
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,619]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - I am  = Failure Post Office Message Preparing Sequence, failureID = 9006, sourceEPSecScheme = OAUTH2, sourceEPRowCount = 1, isSourceEPAvailable = true
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,619]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - Message = Preparing the 9006 post office message, destHttpCode = 400
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,688] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.OAuthConfiguredHTTPEndpoint} - Could not generate access token for oauth configured http endpoint null org.apache.synapse.endpoints.auth.AuthException: Error while accessing the Token URL. HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,688]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - text = An unexpected error occured onError executed, message = Could not generate access token for oauth configured http endpoint null org.apache.synapse.endpoints.auth.AuthException: Error while accessing the Token URL. HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request, code = 303003, detail = Could not generate access token for oauth configured http endpoint null org.apache.synapse.endpoints.auth.AuthException: Error while accessing the Token URL. HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request, exception = Could not generate access token for oauth configured http endpoint null org.apache.synapse.endpoints.auth.AuthException: Error while accessing the Token URL. HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
[2023-11-29 14:17:23,688] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} - APIGW-Exception:Invalid body field: residentialSwitchMatchRequest.services[0].action,APIGW-Exception-Code:24,APIGW-Exception-System:APIGW,Connection:keep-alive,Content-Length:95,Content-Type:application/json,Date:Wed, 29 Nov 2023 14:17:23 GMT,scope:api://totsco.3dflyingmonsters.co.uk/.default, Unexpected error sending message back org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport out has not been set
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:432)

we are trying to generate the token here we are using client credentials grant type. but log states "Could not generate access token for oauth configured http endpoint **null** org.apache.synapse.endpoints.auth.AuthException: Error while accessing the Token URL. HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"

we are able to generate tokens for other customers but for this customer we are getting issue.

Comment: As per the logs shared, my understanding is that you are passing the Token Endpoint URL and the credentials via an API and trying to generate an Access token using it, and please correct me if my understanding is wrong. This seems to be an issue with the request dispatched from the API Manager as the destination server responded with a 400 Bad request. Please do double check the request parameters and the constructed payload for any bad interpretations. Please do share the APIM version that you are trying out and also try disabling the chunking from the mediation sequence prior to request.

Comment: Hi @Athiththan, Yes we are passing the Token URL and credentials via API. we are using APIM v4.1, we checked the request parameters and its correct as per your we will disable the disable the chinking, 
we also trying to decode the ERROR CODE: 303003, in which scenario we receive this error code.